# Routing error: uninitialized constant Users::OmiauthCallbackController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

trying to get users to login using facebook but i get

routing error: uninitialized constant Users::OmiauthCallbackController error

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

```
def facebook

    @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash auth_hash
            if @user.persisted?
                    sign_in_and_redirect @user
            else
                session["devise.user_attributes"] = @user.attributes
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url, notice: "Oops, something went wrong"
            end
        end

    private
```

def auth_hash
            request.env['omniauth.auth']
        end
end

routes file

Fbapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omiauth_callback'}
  resources :posts

get "pages/home"
  root "pages#home"

```
user rb file

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

   def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
        find_by_auth_hash(auth_hash) || create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
   end

   def self.find_by_auth_hash(auth_hash)
        where(
                  provider: auth_hash.provider,
              uid: auth_hash.uid
              ).first
    end

   def self.create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    create(
                provider: auth_hash.provider,
                uid: auth_hash.uid,
              email: auth_hash.info.email,
            name: auth_hash.info.name,
            oauth_token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
            oauth_expires_at: Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at)
             )

   end 

   def password_required?
        super && provider.blank?
   end

   def update_with_password(params, *options) 
        if encrypted_password.blank?
                update_attributes(params, *options)

  else
        super
  end
end
```

end

```
def facebook 
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  end

  def get_profile_info
      self.facebook.get_object("me")
  end

  def get_location
    h = get_profile_info["location"]
    h["name"]

  end 

  def get_books
    self.facebook.get_connection("me", "books")
  end

  def get_profile_picture
    self.facebook.get_picture(uid)
  end


end
```

Comment: can you paste the rest of your class

Comment: and what do you have in your routes.rb file? for example, i'd expect something like 'devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }'

Comment: Neil he meant edit your post and paste it there with the code properly formatted there... not in the comments.

Comment: added code as discussed

Answer (score 1):

Misspelled something in my routes file. It should have said omniauth_callbacks

```
Fbapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}
  resources :posts

  get "pages/home"
  root "pages#home"
```